# Why are my setInterval and setTimeout Animations behaving unexpectedly when switching windows

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout, setinterval, requestanimationframe

https://codepen.io/aswinckr/pen/RJvKjq

This is a two part question -

I'm trying to build a continuous infinite loop animation with plain javascript with `setInterval` and `setTimeout` methods with applying css properties. When i switch browser tabs and return to this after a while my animations seem to behave very unexpectedly. Why does this happen??

After reading online I understand that `requestAnimationFrame` is recommended way to do animations using javascript. In my case i'm using JS to trigger transform and scale properties in css with a `transition` property. Even if i were to use `requestAnimationFrame` with a ease or bezier function lets say, how would I take care of the `setTimeout` functionality? Where after animating between first and second cards to repeat the animation from second to third..

The link to codepen is pasted above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the browser wants to save resources....

Comment: Browsers slow interval timers way, way down on inactive browser tabs to save energy and battery etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks for pointing me to this. In the example showed he still uses setTimeout. Does that not get affected in the performance optimization? Or is it just setInterval